# windbg coredump analysis address with "bad"

Tags: c++, windbg

I have a corruption memory heap problem with an application.
by using windbg and a dump file of the crash as an input I have the following output with dd esp command

```
0:002> dd esp
00000000`03e3e490  14badf55 00000000 03e3e8c0 00000000
00000000`03e3e4a0  00000000 00000000 03e3e8c0 00000000
00000000`03e3e4b0  03e3e8c0 00000000 6b0064f2 00000000
00000000`03e3e4c0  03e3f030 00000000 6b002510 00000000
00000000`03e3e4d0  00000000 00000000 03dfede8 00000000
00000000`03e3e4e0  c0000005 00000000 00000000 7d6210e8
00000000`03e3e4f0  00000002 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000`03e3e500  00000000 00001000 78b83980 036b0000
```

There is this adress : 14badf55

I really don't know how to interpret this "bad"..

Is anyone have an idea of the meaning of this bad ?

EDIT:

when I try to use  this command :

```
 u 14badf55
```

the following output comes :

```
00000000`14badf55 ??              ???
                ^ Memory access error in 'u 14badf55'
```

The .ecxr command give me :

```
rax=0000000003e3e488 rbx=0000000003e3e8c0 rcx=0000000003e3dfb0
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=000000006b005a17 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=000000006b006369 rsp=0000000003e3e490 rbp=0000000003dfede8
 r8=000000006b00254a  r9=0000000003e3e4d8 r10=0000000000000007
r11=0000000000000000 r12=000000006b01fe90 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000003e3f110 r15=0000000078b83980
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=0000  es=0000  fs=0000  gs=0000             efl=00000204
wow64!Wow64NotifyDebugger+0x9:
00000000`6b006369 b001            mov     al,1
```

Comment: Isn't it just a memory location in hexadecimal form?

Comment: that just looks like any other memory address..looks like you have an access violation. Did you try `.ecxr` command?

Comment: @Naveen: I am a new user of windbg I don't know this command, I will documment me on it

Comment: `badf` is no different from `dfed` in a later part of the dump. They are just valid int or pointer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the c0000005 output in the file. This is the sign of a access violation.

Run the following:
- .cxr 00000000`03e3e4e0      (To set the exception context)
- kL                          (to get a stack trace)